# href with custom protocol not respond in Phonegap 3.6.3

Tags: android, cordova

I'm creating a APP with Phonegap, this APP have a link with this:

```
<a href="bitcoin:1mn....">Send me coins</a>
```

This link in Phonegap 3.5.0 is detected on click and the android intent is binded, this open my phone bitcoin wallet. But in new version of Phonegap, 3.6.3, this nots works. Maybe it's a bug? Maybe I need a new permission that not it's in docs?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your config.xml

```
<access origin="bitcoin:*" launch-external="yes"/>
```

This works for some schemes, if it doesn't work, then you have to use inAppBrowser plugin

Install it with this command

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser
```

and Use it like this:

```
<a href="window.open('bitcoin:1mn....', '_system');">Send me coins</a>
```

Comment: Oh, it works for other urls, I'll edit my answer, you have to use inAppBrowser then

Comment: This is only for Android? :O, not for iOS or Windows Phone?